# Accessing appsetting(web.config) value in client side in orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

How to access the web.config value in my custom module javascript code(client side), In orchard.

Comment: Basically, you can't access config information from javascript directly, but you can implement new WebAPI to read the data you want from web.config, then call it as ajax request from your javascript side. Hope I can understand your question, if no, please provide more information on what data you want to access?

Comment: What are you trying to access/load?
If you want to save some settings you should just write your own settingsPart and attach it to the site

Comment: It should be noted that in general Orchard doesn't use web.config (or as little as possible), because it's a global resource that ignores multi-tenancy and modularity. Depending on the scenario, there are better places to put configuration.